# Отключение правой кнопки мыши на windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, реестр, windows-8

Друзья, знаю как при добавлении параметра [DWORD](https://windata.ru/windows-xp/faq-xp/otmena-zapuska-kontekstnogo-menyu-pravoj-knopkoj/) отключать правую кнопку мыши, но сообразить как .reg написать для добавления/удаления этого параметра - нет. Кто может помочь с написанием такого скрипта?
Задача такая, что надо при открытии файла "Выкл. правую кнопку мыши" она выключалась, и аналогично при открытии "Вкл. правую кнопку мыши" снова начинала работать.
Вроде как работать это должно на всех версиях Windows, но если это принципиально, нужно под Windows 7 и 8, 8.1

Comment: `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER...` - добавить значение. `[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER...` удалить значение.

Comment: @donRumata Напиши плиз ответом. Поставлю +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формат `.reg` файлов в Windows предполагает не только добавление или изменение ключей и их значений, но ещё и удаление.

Для того, чтобы удалить ключ и все вложенные элементы, надо поставить `-` перед этим самым ключом.

На примере очистки истории монтируемых сетевых папок:

`type clean-network-disks-history.reg`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Map Network Drive MRU]
```